# mysql: (pdo) continue at last position without using OFFSET

Tags: mysql, pdo

I wish to retrieve around 200 million profiles using PDO.
It is a partitioned table, so it does not have a primary key, it's sorted with INNODBs internal primary key.

I need to retrieve the data in internal sort order for performance, so using SORT BY some_id   and to continue from there would not work for performance reasons.

Using LIMIT OFFSET would not work at all, OFFSET 100 million or more would take ages, the RAM is by far not enough to take all the terrabyte of table data into cache.

I would need something that fetches a chunk of rows, remembers the internal position and continues with next call.

**Update**
I was digging a bit and the problem seems familiar, it was solved in Oracle by having ROWID and ROWNUM which refer to the internal id.
It seems we have such an id in innodb as well but it's not queryable ?!
That sounds like a significant disadvantage of mysql for performant query.

Table def:

```
    CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `intern_id` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `l` varchar(196) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `i` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ex` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `edu` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `nc` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nj` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jt` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `cn` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `fpe` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1/0',
  `pbu` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `cii` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `unmatched_facts` varchar(2048) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt_snapshot` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `change_small` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `change_significant` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jta` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `cna` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnia` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `ut_created` int(11) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `reserve_int_2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reserve_vc1` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `reserve_vc2` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `reserve_vc_3` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `intern_id` (`intern_id`),
  KEY `state_name` (`state_name`),
  KEY `city_name` (`city_name`),
  KEY `i` (`i`),
  KEY `country_name` (`country_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
  PARTITION BY KEY (`country_name`)
  PARTITIONS 30
```

Comment: This may be more suited to the dba forum

Comment: `OFFSET 100 million or more would take ages` why? can you provide your schema? and query you are running? by PDO you mean php PDO ?

Comment: yes, PHP PDO. But it probably doesn't matter.
OFFSET 100 million takes ages, half an hour or longer for a query that takes 0.5 seconds to run through with offset 0. 
Mysql has to search for the 100 million possion first, then it can retrieve the rows.

Comment: @Solarflare I just came to that conclusion ;/ 
It seems innodb does have it, internal only.
That really sucks, they have PARTITION support for so long but without a ROWID you can't really use it's potential

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL does not offer an uncached server side cursor, so you cannot do that without a primary key. I am not really sure what you mean by "it is a partitioned table, so it does not have a primary key". As Alex suggested, could you share your table definition, maybe there is a viable pk that you could add/use.

Comment: @Solarflare it's a huge table, sharing it would distract from the problem.

I partition by a value that can not be in a primary key, as I HAVE to have all unique keys in partition defintion I had to remove the primary key and replace it with a normal key (it's a readonly table).
I suppose I'll have to go the ORDER BY route, giving up the sequential access.

Comment: just provide your schema definition. It seem you have no idea what we are asking for. So just run `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;`  and provide us the output. And provide your query you want to offset. I don't see any proof that MySQL can't handle that number of records yet. It is just your opinion, no proofs where provided. If you have your php script - that would help as well.

Comment: Do you have anything unique in your table? E.g. the profile id? You can simply generate an artificial primary key, e.g. your partition value + profile id. If you really have nothing unique, add something, e.g. a uuid. The table description can help in estimating that, even if you do not think it would help.

Comment: I've attached the definition.
@Solarflare, yes I have unique "id" which was originally an autoincrement key.
I am using it already but it's 2 times slower than when using the internal ID.

When I use "WHERE id > XX ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000" it will reorder the table from internal structure to id.
When I just use "LIMIT 1000" it will use the internal sort order without having to search 1000 sequencial IDs from all over the table file.

Comment: If you can make `country_name` not null (e.g. with `default ''`), `primary key (id, country_name)` should solve your problem. If it has to be nullable, you may want to duplicate that column to a not-null column (in e.g. a trigger) and use this for the pk. You may also want to reevaluate why you use partitions in the first place; I assume you expect some performance gain when you limit your queries to specific countries, but you may overestimate the effect (and underestimate the negative effect on situations like this one).

Comment: @Solarflare Yea I am not completely sure about the partitioning.
The thing is that 90% of the searches target United States and it was spread all over a terrabyte of data.
With partitionioning it's condensed in the same data.
I've had mixed benchmark results, sometimes much faster sometimes slower than before.

About the index:
Would you recommend that sort of index ?
I did not do that because "id" is a clean, small index.
What would mysql do internally if a varchar like country_name is mixed to the index ?

Comment: This is drifting a away and should be a new question. If you want/need partitioning, you have to live with the consequences (usually a dealbreaker: unique keys; here: a little bigger pk (with probably neglectable consequences)). But again, this is drifting away. You should ask a new question where you explain why you want that partitioning, ask how to set a proper pk, possible disadvantages of doing it, and for alternatives to your partitioning that might also solve your original problem (as partitioning rarely solves the problem you think it does, and generates many new ones).